# Problema ao fechar a Lightbox quando chamo AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou com problemas quando neste site http://santins.com.br/_z/holcim acesso a sessão `PROJETO` e clico em `RELEASES`. Enquanto eu não clico em nenhum título que carrega via `AJAX` o conteúdo da postagem, a `LIGHTBOX` fecha, mas ao clicar no título e o ajax carregar o conteúdo não consigo mais fechá-la. O que pode ser esse problema?

Meu AJAX:

```
// Classe para posts AJAX
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $("a.ajax").click(function(){
            var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
            var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
            $("#tabs").html('<div class="loading">loading...</div>');
        $("#tabs").load(post_url);
        return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Testei aqui, e fechou normalmente. O problema que achei foi que o conteúdo não tem scrollbar para poder rolar e ver ele todo, fora isso não avistei nenhum, estou usando Mozilla Firefox